# React native losing performance while running

Tags: react-native

So I'm working on a react native app, and whenever I start the app it is running just fine with about 60fps. But for some reason whenever the app just runs for a while, both the UI and the JS thread start dropping frames considerably until maybe about 6 to 7 fps. If I say running, I mean literally just having it open while not giving any inputs or controlling it in any way. I have run it through the android studio profiler and from what I could tell, its all looking pretty normal, I dont see any big spikes or drops in cpu load nor memory or energy consumption. The drop in performance also happens when using the app as intended.

I noticed this behaviour both on my galaxy a52s as well as in emulators (and I think a galaxy note as well, forgot the specific phone model). For compatibility reasons its running on **RN 0.59.9**.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what this could be?

Edit: 
There are some processes that are periodically running, but the only thing thats really running continously is a map from react-native-maps. I just tested the performance while having it not rendered, and it seems like the problems with the performance come from that. Thanks for the help still.

Comment: I think more info will help. Do you have any long-running animations or processes? What is the app doing when it's not doing anything? There are no CPU spikes, but does usage steadily increase? There is probably something recursive in your app that doesn't have a proper exit condition

Comment: If you have long-running processes in your app, log out when they start up, so you can see if they're starting more than you want them to

Comment: The loads didnt really increase at all and all that stuff, but as I said in the edit the performance hit came from react-native-maps so I guess thats that. Thanks you guys for the help